# r customize color with swimplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
SwimArm <- swimmer_plot(df=Swim.Plot,
                        id='SUBJID',
                        end='swim_month',
                        name_fill='ARM',
                        id_order='ARM',
                        col="black",
                        increasing = FALSE,
                        alpha=0.75,width=.8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Time since Treatment (months)",breaks = seq(0,18,by=3))
```

I'm currently using swimplot package in r, and would like to customize plot of color below.
It seems that the package automatically chooses color of the line, and I would like to do this part manually.
Can you please tell me what I should do?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Do `scale_fill_manual` (for strip fill) or `scale_color_manual` (for strip border colour) work? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html

Comment: See also here in the middle of the page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/swimplot/vignettes/Introduction.to.swimplot.html